# Check geometries distorting polygons when removing gaps

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, geometry, distortion, gap

Using QGIS 3.10.9 with the check geometries plugin (v0.1), and I have a simple polygon layer as a test run with a deliberate gap.

[image: Polygon layer with a deliberate gap]

I use the check geometries plugin with the topology check 'check for gaps smaller than..' enabled and set to 100 map units sqr.

[image: Topology checks enabled]

The deliberate gap is identified by the plugin but when I try to resolve it using the default method 'add gap to neighbouring polygon with longest shared edge' it distorts the shape of the polygon rather than filling in the gap.

[image: gap detected]

[image: default resolution method]

[image: polygon is distorted]

I have previously used this plugin to fill in gaps and didn't come across this issue then.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This kind of questions can be addressed by QGIS devs themselves at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/ You can create an issue there and provide some details or even test data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on the tolerance, try putting a value of 1E-8